# Getting product name + categories + other attributes from database directly?

Tags: magento-1.7, product-attribute

**Magento 1.7.0.2**

I got the attribute ids I want to get from the database, they are 426, 74, 439, 92, 81, 425. In addition to those I want the product name, sku and the categories the product is in. The products visibility should be `catalog,search` only.

This is what I got so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
cpev.`value` as Name,
cpe.sku as SKU,
#cpe.*,
#cpev.*,
ea.attribute_code
FROM
catalog_product_entity_varchar cpev
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity cpe ON cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id
INNER JOIN eav_attribute ea on cpev.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id where ea.attribute_id in (426, 74, 439, 92, 81, 425);
```

Not exactly what I need, but maybe a start. How could I get the data I need from the DB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Please try with the following query.

```
SELECT
cpe.sku as SKU,
if(cpev.attribute_id = 71,cpev.`value`,null) as Name,
cv.value as category_name,
max(if(cpev.attribute_id = 426,cpev.`value`,null)) as '426',
max(if(cpev.attribute_id = 74,cpev.`value`,null)) as '74',
max(if(cpev.attribute_id = 439,cpev.`value`,null)) as '439',
max(if(cpev.attribute_id = 92,cpev.`value`,null)) as '92',
max(if(cpev.attribute_id = 81,cpev.`value`,null)) as '81',
max(if(cpev.attribute_id = 425,cpev.`value`,null)) as '425'
FROM `catalog_product_entity` cpe
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar`cpev ON cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id
LEFT JOIN  `catalog_category_product` AS at_category ON at_category.product_id = cpe.entity_id
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_varchar` as cv on at_category.category_id = cv.entity_id
GROUP BY cpe.sku
```

Comment: Looking good for a start, but its missing the columns for the mentioned attributes (426, 74, 439, 92, 81, 425)

Comment: so you want all other attributes of product as a separate columns in query output. right?  like...need to display attribute values after category_name column? like wise?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I need a separate column for all the attributes mentioned. The name of the column should be the attribute code.

Comment: No idea how to solve it?

Comment: I have edited the query above please check with it and let me know it is working or not.

Comment: Did you check? is it working for you?